# Usar API EWS com reflection em C#

Tags: c#, api, dll, reflexão, outlook

Eu estou tentando usar a API do EWS no SSIS Script Task, mas o servidor não tem a dll correspondente: `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll`

Então, utilizar reflection é a única solução que encontrei, o arquivo da dll está no servidor disponivel para uso.

Eu preciso instanciar uma subclasse de uma classe abstrata, mas o compilador da esta mensagem de erro: Não encontrado o construtor de `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo`

Esse é o meu código, eu tentei as soluções a seguir para pegar o tipo `SearchFilter.IsEqualTo` mas sem sucesso:

```
Type typeSearchFilter = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter");

var typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo = typeSearchFilter.GetNestedType("IsEqualTo");

Type typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo0 = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo");

Type typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo1 = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.IsEqualTo");

dynamic searcherFilter = Activator.CreateInstance(typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo, new object[] { folderSchemaDisplayName, folder});
```